# find all possible vectors, with a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, transformation

I don't know how to approach the next problem.

they give me

[image]

that are bases of a vector space V and let f: V → V be the linear transformation such that [image]

All v∈V such that [image] are

they gave me these 4 answers:

[image]

I did several accounts but none of them gave me similar, then I saw that it says f (v) = f (v), does it mean that the transform gives a transform? I'm very confused

Answer (score 1):

$f(2v_1 + v_2 - v_3)$ is some vector. Let us call that $\mathbf w$. It turns out that $\mathbf w = 2v_1 + 3v_2 - v_3$ but we don't actually need to know it as anything more than "$\mathbf w$" for the solution.

Anyways, so we have an equation $f(\mathbf v) = \mathbf w$ and you will hopefully recall that the solution set of such an equation is a translate of the kernel (AKA null space) of $f$.

$$\{\mathbf v : f(\mathbf v) = \mathbf w\} = \mathbf v_0 + \ker f = \{\mathbf v_0 + \mathbf u : \mathbf u \in \ker f\} $$

where $\mathbf v_0$ is any particular solution to $f(\mathbf v) = \mathbf w$.

So for this problem we need two things:

1. we need $\mathbf v_0$
2. we need $\ker f$

For 1., we know already that $f(2v_1 + v_2 - v_3) = \mathbf w$ since that was the definition of $\mathbf w$. Therefore, we can take $\mathbf v_0 = 2v_1 + v_2 - v_3$ as a particular solution. This explains also why all but one of the proposed answers includes $2v_1 + v_2 - v_3$.

So now if $\ker f = \operatorname{Span}\{\mathbf u\}$ (which I'll leave up to you to solve), then the solutions to $f(\mathbf v) = \mathbf w$ is

$$\mathbf v = 2v_1 + v_2 - v_3 + \alpha \mathbf u$$

for some $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$.

If you need a hint on solving for $\ker f$, notice that the first two columns of $M_{B',B}(f)$ are identical.

Comment: I have seen that not all the vectors of the matrix are linearly independent (1, -1,2) (1,2, -1) would it be the base, right? But I don't understand what you mean by Span {u}, sorry is that maybe in my country it is different, unfortunately here they do not explain these issues very well, so I have to be independent and study on my own in these forums. (sorry for my English). So I would have f(v) =  2v1 + v2 − v3 + α (−v1 + v2) with α∈R right? Can you explain that to me about Span{u} in another way please, I would like to learn it well

Comment: How do you solve $f(\mathbf v) = \mathbf 0$ and how do you write the answer? It should be in your textbook or something. @emprendedoresdealma

Comment: I don't understand, isn't it α (−v1 + v2)? why ?

Comment: @emprendedoresdealma The matrix goes from $B'$ to $B$. Let me write $B' = \{\mathbf u_1, \mathbf u_2, \mathbf u_3\}$. So because the first two columns of that matrix are identical, that means that $f(\mathbf u_1) = f(\mathbf u_2)$. Therefore $f(\mathbf u_1 - \mathbf u_2) = \mathbf 0$.

Comment: I'm confused: /. That Span {u} confuses me a lot. I don't know what you mean by that. and I don't understand why it has to be v = 2v1 + v2 − v3 + α (v2 + 2v3)..

Comment: @emprendedoresdealma look at your textbook for examples of solving $f(\mathbf v) = \mathbf w$. Maybe make a new question if you need to and be very clear about what examples you know and what concepts are familiar to you. I don't have the time for a dialogue in the comments. Also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_span is what I mean by span. You can likely find that article in your native language albeit with less detail than the English page.